# Scipy LSQSphereBivariateSpline : hanging, and how to choose knots?

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation, spline, least-squares

I'm working on some python code to interpolate irregular data onto a 180° lat x 360° lon spherical grid. The code is currently hanging when I call the following:

```
def geo_interp(lats,lons,data,grid_size_deg):

        deg2rad = pi/180.
        new_lats = np.linspace(grid_size_deg, 180, 180) * deg2rad
        new_lons = np.linspace(grid_size_deg, 360, 360) * deg2rad

        knotst, knotsp = new_lats.copy(), new_lons.copy()
        knotst[0] += .0001
        knotst[-1] -= .0001
        knotsp[0] += .0001
        knotsp[-1] -= .0001

        lut = LSQSphereBivariateSpline(lats.ravel(),lons.ravel(),data.T.ravel(),knotst,knotsp)

        data_interp = lut(new_lats, new_lons)
        return data_interp
```

The arrays I'm using as arguments when I call the above subroutine all fit the requirements of LSQSphereBivariateSpline as listed in the documentation. When I run it, it takes much longer than I feel like it should take to process a 180x360 dataset.

When I run the script with python -m trace --trace, the last line of output before nothing happens for a long time is
 `fitpack2.py(1025):                                                      w=w, eps=eps)`

As far as I can tell, line 1025 of fitpack2.py is in a comment, which is even more confusing.

So my questions are:
1. Is there a way to tell if it's hanging or just very slow?
2. If it's hanging, how might I fix it?

The only thing I can think of is that I have no idea what I'm doing as far as choosing knots. Is there a good way to choose those? I just went with the grid I'll be interpolating to later, since the example in the doc seemed to be an arbitrary grid.

UPDATE: It finally finished after about 3 hours but the "interpolated data" looked like random noise. Also, if this is relevant, as far as I can tell LSQSphereBivariateSpline is the only function I can use for this because my lats and lons are not strictly increasing.

Also, I should add that when it finished it output the following warning: `Warning (from warnings module):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/scipy/interpolate/fitpack2.py", line 1029
    warnings.warn(message)
UserWarning: 
WARNING. The coefficients of the spline returned have been computed as the
         minimal norm least-squares solution of a (numerically) rank
         deficient system (deficiency=16336, rank=48650). Especially if the rank
         deficiency, which is computed by 6+(nt-8)*(np-7)+ier, is large,
         the results may be inaccurate. They could also seriously depend on
         the value of eps.`

---

**SOLUTION:** I had far too many knots, causing both the glacial pace and the useless results.

Comment: Yes, the FITPACK spline fitting routine probably tries to least-squares solve n x n problem where n=360*180*k (where k ~ 9 is degrees of freedom in the spline). This is too big for fortran code written in the 80s.

Comment: It would be great if you post your solution as an answer and accept it. Also, after doing this, please, remove 'SOLVED' from question title. Thanks.